# Lodash debounce: what does "the system time has gone backwards" mean?

Tags: lodash, debouncing

Recently I am reading the source code of lodash debounce function. I can't figure out why **timeSinceLastCall** could be less than 0 in the **shouldInvoke** method. The comment says that the system time has gone backwards. What does it mean? The source code of lodash debounce is here: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.8.0-npm/debounce.js

Comment: I means pretty much exactly what it says. It's a precaution for if the system time is changed to some time in the past.

Comment: @4castle, do you mean it is a precaution for changing system time into the past when the timer is scheduled?

Comment: @4castle, and if I don't change system time any way then the **timeSinceLastCall** will never be less than 0, right?

Comment: Yes and yes, that is correct

Comment: @4castle, thanks a lot for your help.